# Styles not working with support library 22.1.0

Tags: android, styles, android-support-library

I used to have:

```
<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/dark_blue</item>
<item name="colorControlActivated">@color/dark_blue</item>
<item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/dark_blue</item>
```

and it was working well until I updated support library to 22.1.0, now the colors are the system default.

styles.xml

```
<resources>

<style name="WifiSentinel" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/light_blue</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/WifiSentinelTextAppearance</item>
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/MyTextViewStyle</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/dark_blue</item>
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/EditTextStyle</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/dark_blue</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/dark_blue</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/dark_blue</item>
</style>

<style name="WifiSentinelBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/dark_blue</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/white</item>
    <item name="background">@color/dark_blue</item>
</style>

<style name="EditTextStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/dark_blue</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/dark_blue</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/dark_blue</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTextViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/WifiSentinelTextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="WifiSentinelTextAppearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/dark_blue</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">15dp</item>
</style>

<style name="WifiSentinelTextAppearance.Large" parent="@style/WifiSentinelTextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textSize">18dp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

I don't know what to do or if this is a bug or something.

**EDIT**: I will use `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0` until I solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Had simular issue and changed *background* to *android:background* do the job

```
<item name="android:background">@color/dark_blue</item>
```

Comment: Hi, the problem is with colorControlNormal, Activated and Highlight, not with background.

Comment: *<item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/red</item>*   not working !! but works fine in L

Comment: Support Library v25.0.0 and these attributes are still not working (in conjunction with a ton of other issues).